# Grid view Item template? In Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In asp.net web page, i am using gridview, in item template i am using check box which is for displaying status. if status is 1 cheked is ture if 0 it is unchecked i write the code like this.

```
  <asp:CheckBox ID="chkone" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("status").ToString()=="1"? true :false %>' > </CheckBox>
```

it will work when "status" is int [datatype, in database], if it is char(2) data type it is not working, can you help me.

Comment: Have you tested and working fine as expected if data is int? If your status column is either 1 or 0, then just go with int value in DB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
<%# Eval("status").ToString().Trim()=="1"? true :false %>
```

I believe char(2) will be padding your number with a space.

I might also mention that

```
{condition} ? true : false;
```

is somewhat redundant and you should just have

```
{condition}
```

Comment: YA THANK YOU SYNXSIS, IT IS WORKING FINE, I WILL TEST ONCE AGAIN AND MARK YOUR ANSWER